# How to use the modal verbs Shall and Will when using them to give commands?

Tags: modal-verbs

For example-
"You shall attend the conference". 
"You will attend the conference".
Is there any difference between them?

Comment: Few people use _shall_ in this context any more. In fact many people don't use _shall_ in any context.

Comment: @ColinFine, the conventional theory (as we had been taught) is that SHALL follows first person (I, and We), and WILL the remaining (referred to as third person), called ordinary future.   If it goes the other way, it adds more emphasis to it. In modern English language use, it must have undergone change(s).

Comment: Yes, @RamPillai, and I'm one of the people who continues to use _shall_ with the first person, especially in a question, _shall I?_. But apart from that, and the use in regulations and standards, _shall_ is pretty well dead. Other than in Cinderella (_you **shall** go to the ball!_) I would be surprised to hear anyone say _you shall_. That's why I didn't answer with the traditional complex answer.

Comment: @ColinFine, Agree with you, fully.

Comment: Is it correct that we use will with first person and shall with second and third person when we want to express strong determination?

Comment: @user11634197: that is what some of the books tell you. That is not what most native English speakers do, which is why I commented as I did.